# No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection timeout calling ismaster on '10.0.0.106:27017']

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, php-mongodb

i have this issue with laravel project use mongoDB

```
ConnectionTimeoutException in Collection.php line 192:
No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection
timeout calling ismaster on '10.0.0.106:27017']
```

i did

```
 service ngnix restart
```

but its not work still same i dont know how solve it

Comment: This seems like a question for https://serverfault.com/

Comment: i think its not the same

Comment: I am facing this issue multiple times, have checked all ports and allowed all IP addresses. but the issue still persists as Error : No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [socket timeout calling ismaster ...

Answer (score 2):

the reason is `mongod` server not support ipv6 by default, but the `systemOS` used ipv6.
you can delete the ipv6 on system:
remove this line

```
::1 localhost' from /etc/hosts
```

or, enable the mongod ipv6 support !
eg:

```
./bin/mongod --filePermissions 0777 --ipv6
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I changed php version. The solution for me was to add mongo extension to php.ini file of the new php version. My php.ini on mac

```
/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini
```

Just add

```
;extension=mongodb.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this is there are too many open connection requests  to  database. Please check if u have any ajax calls running in ur application. you can login to cloudmongo where you have hosted the database cluster and see the number of collections going beyond 100.You might be having too many dbs in the same cluster. I suggest you move few dbs to another cluster.

Hope it helps.